# Check if multiple row values exists in a Pandas column on Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, validation

I have a dataframe which contains individual strings from larger, descriptive column and I want to validate that the individual strings are present in the description.

| Fruit | Plant | Location | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | Malus domestica | Worldwide | Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. |
| banana | Musa | Indomalayan realm | Musa genus includes flowering plants producing edible bananas native to Australasia. |
| grapes | Vitis | Northern Hemisphere | Vitis genus is made up of species of vining plants predominantly from the Northern Hemisphere. |
| pears | Pyrus calleryana | China | Pyrus calleryana is a species of pear tree native to China |
| Strawberry |  | Worldwide | Fragaria collectively known as the strawberries, which are cultivated worldwide for their fruit. |

I want something like this:

| Fruit | Plant | Location | Description | Validation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | Malus domestica | Worldwide | Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. | True |
| banana | Musa | Indomalayan realm | Musa genus includes flowering plants producing edible bananas native to Australasia. | False |
| grapes | Vitis | Northern Hemisphere | Vitis genus is made up of species of vining plants predominantly from the Northern Hemisphere. | False |
| pears | Pyrus calleryana | China | Pyrus calleryana is a species of pear tree native to China | True |
| Strawberry |  | Worldwide | Fragaria collectively known as the strawberries, which are cultivated worldwide for their fruit. | True |

Bonus points if there is a way to determine what is missing, for example something like this:

| Fruit | Plant | Location | Description | Validation | discrepancy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | Malus domestica | Worldwide | Apple trees are cultivated worldwide and are the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. | True | N/A |
| banana | Musa | Indomalayan realm | Musa genus includes flowering plants producing edible bananas native to Australasia. | False | Indomalayan realm |
| grapes | Vitis | Northern Hemisphere | Vitis genus is made up of species of vining plants predominantly from the Northern Hemisphere. | False | grapes |
| pears | Pyrus calleryana | China | Pyrus calleryana is a species of pear tree native to China | True | N/A |
| Strawberry |  | Worldwide | Fragaria collectively known as the strawberries, which are cultivated worldwide for their fruit. | False | Missing Plant |

Finding the discrepancy isn't important, but I just need some help with the validations.
Thanks!

Comment: Most of your `true` rows don't look like they contain all strings. Neither `apple` nor `Malus domestica` appear in the `Description` field

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd dataframe, I think it's hard to create a function that return **True** when we try to search **Strawberry** in a string that contains **strawberries** (or **pears** - **pear**). The code below might help you a little.

```
Val = []
for fruit, plant, loc, des in zip (df['Fruit'],df['Plant'],df['Location'],df['Description']):
    print(fruit, plant.split(' ')[0].lower(), loc, des)
    Val.append((fruit.lower() in des.lower()) and 
                 (plant.split(' ')[0].lower() in des.lower()) and 
                 (loc.lower() in des.lower()))
df['Validation'] = Val
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your required output:

- nan column will not be considered in the evaluation.
- If a column has more than one word, and a single word is found, we can assign True.
- If another form of the word is found, such as plural, we can assign True.

For the first part of the problem, the below code should help:

```
import pandas as pd
from thefuzz import fuzz
from collections import defaultdict


data = pd.read_excel("fruit_table.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
data["Validation"] = ""


def process_text(strings, y):
    
    interim_results = []
    
    for string in strings:
        
        if string != "nan":
            if fuzz.ratio(string, y)>=70:
                result = True
            else:
                result = False
        else:
            result = True
            
        interim_results.append(result)
        
    final_result = any(interim_results)

    return final_result



def validation(x):
    
    splitted_text = x["Description"].replace(".","").split()
    
    fruit = x["Fruit"].split()
    plant = x["Plant"].split()
    location = x["Location"].split()

    labels_dict = defaultdict(list)
    
    for text in splitted_text:
        
        label_fruit = process_text(fruit, text)
        label_plant = process_text(plant, text)
        label_location = process_text(location, text)
        
        labels_dict["-".join(fruit)].append(label_fruit)
        labels_dict["-".join(plant)].append(label_plant)
        labels_dict["-".join(location)].append(label_location)
        
    fruit_label = any(labels_dict["-".join(fruit)])
    plant_label = any(labels_dict["-".join(plant)])
    location_label = any(labels_dict["-".join(location)])
        
    label = all([fruit_label, plant_label, location_label])
    
    return label


data["Validation"] = data.apply(validation, axis=1)
data
```

Output:

[image]